# Why doesn't the kubernetes documentation show the valid mappings for requests or capacity?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, persistent-volumes

In kubernetes the correct syntax for specifying the storage requirement of a persistentVolume is:

```
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
```

when inspecting the documentation reference or using `kubectl explain` I would expect to see the `storage` key noted in the docs however it's absent, it's not clear from the documentation which mappings are allowed inside the capacity section of a persistentVolume spec and how to know that "storage" is the correct key to denote the disk requirement of the persistent volume.

```
~ kubectl explain --recursive persistentvolume.spec.capacity

FIELDS:
  .
  .
   capacity <map[string]string>
  .
  .
```

You can see examples of course but that doesn't tell me what other possible keys there are, just what there is in the example.

In a similar vein, I can see from this [table tucked away in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-requests-and-limits-of-pod-and-container) that allowed keys inside `resources.requests` are: `[cpu, memory, hugepages-<size>]` but if I call `kubectl explain --recursive pod.spec.resources` I would expect to see:

```
FIELDS:
   limits   <map[string]string>
     cpu
     memory
     hugepages-<size>
   requests <map[string]string>
     cpu
     memory
     hugepages-<size>
```

but instead you see just:

```
FIELDS:
   limits   <map[string]string>
   requests <map[string]string>
```

Whilst the datatype make it clears that `limits` and `requests` are both mappings the docs don't make it easy to find out what the valid mappings are.

For these mapping, other than finding examples, how do I know what all the possible valid mappings are, and how come they don't appear in the `kubectl explain` output

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible explanations, but most probable are:

- it just wasn't updated,
- design choice.

Remember, docs are written by people, not generated. When things are getting updated, certain changes may not be properly described.